# React: Nested Array Form - Input field onChange handler

Tags: reactjs, input, onchange

**The form data is set by an the data object. Need help figuring out how to update /handleChange the text inputs**

I've tried unique name, those probably won't work because it wont match the "key" in the object.
Any help / input is appreciated!

Data:

```
export default
  {
    name: "Restaurants Name",
    menu: [
      {
        category: "Appetizers",
        items:
          [ {
              imgurl: "https://source.unsplash.com/400x200/?863127",
              title: "Food 2",
              desc: "",
              price: "500"
            },
            {
              imgurl: "",
              title: "Food 1",
              desc: "",
              price: "300"
            }
          ]
      },
{
        category: "Entree",
        items:
          [ {
              imgurl: "https://source.unsplash.com/400x200/?863127",
              title: "Entree 1",
              desc: "",
              price: "500"
            },
            {
              imgurl: "",
              title: "Entree 1",
              desc: "",
              price: "300"
            }
          ]
      },
    ]
  }
```

Code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./../App.css"
import MenuData from "../data"


function Edit() {

  const [formState, setFormState] = useState(MenuData);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(formState)
  }, []);



  const handleNameChange = (event) => {
    
    const name = event.target.name;
    // console.log(name)

    setFormState(prevState => ({
      formState: {                   // object that we want to update
          ...prevState.formState,    // keep all other key-value pairs
          [name]: event.target.value,      // update the value of specific key

          menu: {
            ...prevState.menu,
            items: {
              ...prevState.menu.items
            }
          }
        
      }
    }))

    // setFormState({
    //   ...formState,
    //   [name]: event.target.value,
    // })



  };

  const handleChange = (categoryIndex, event) => {
    
    // const values = [...formState]
    // values[categoryIndex][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    // setFormState(values);
    const name = event.target.name;

    // setFormState(prevState => ({
    //   formState: {
    //     ...prevState.formState,
    //     menu: {
    //       ...prevState.menu,
    //       items{
    //         ...prevState.items
    //       }
    //     }
    //   }
    // }));


  };

  return (
    <div className="App">      
      <div>

          <input name="nameField" id="nameField" maxLength="300" value={formState.name} onChange={handleNameChange} /> <br />            
          
          {formState.menu && formState.menu.map((menuitem, categoryIndex) => {
                return (
                  <div key={categoryIndex}>
                    <div class="line"></div>
                    <h2>{menuitem.category}</h2> 
                      <input name={"category-" + categoryIndex} id="CategoryField" maxLength="40" categoryIndex={categoryIndex} onChange={event => handleChange(categoryIndex, event)} value={menuitem.category} />
                      {
                        menuitem.items.map((item, index) => {
                          return(
                            <div key={index}>
                              <input name={"title-" + index + categoryIndex} id="titleField" maxLength="40" categoryIndex={categoryIndex} onChange={handleChange} value={item.title} /> <br />
                              <input name="desc" id="descField" maxLength="200" categoryIndex={categoryIndex} onChange={handleChange} value={item.desc} /> 
                              <br /><br />
                            </div>
                          )
                        })
                      } 
                  </div>
                )
              }
            )
          }
                
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Edit;
```

**UPDATED**

- Not able to figure out the onChange function to updated nested items

Comment: What comes back from: `import MenuData from "../data"`? Can you show the console.log of it?

Comment: no issues loading the form, just when i try to edit field values. MenuData comes back as {
    name: "Restaurants Name",
    ........
  }

Comment: This line `const name = [event.target.name];` doesn't look right. just do `const name = event.target.name;`